# Insert all the values from one table to each row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
SLNO     
1    
2   
3
4
5
6
```

and

```
MonthDate
2014-1-1
2014-2-1
2014-3-1
```

How can I merge these two table into one table to get the output like this.

```
SLNO                     MonthDate
1                        2014-1-1
1                        2014-2-1
1                        2014-3-1
2                        2014-1-1
2                        2014-2-1
2                        2014-3-1
3                        2014-1-1
3                        2014-2-1
3                        2014-3-1
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT SLNO , MonthDate
Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT SLNO , MonthDate
Table1 CROSS APPLY Table2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
Select * from t1,t2 order by t1.SLNO
```